# Scanning from dynamodb with out partition key using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

- I need to extract the items from dynamodb which is matching `id, name, role`
- Above 3 are just attributes of the table they are not part key or sort key

Below is the code

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Attr
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('mytable')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response_list = []
    scan_response = table.scan(
        FilterExpression=Attr('id').eq(event['id']) & Attr(
        'name').eq(event['name']) & Attr(
        'role').eq('Manager')
    )
    response_list.extend(scan_response['Items'])
    while scan_response.get('LastEvaluatedKey'):
        scan_response = table.scan(
            FilterExpression=Attr('id').eq(event['id']) & Attr(
        'name').eq(event['name']) & Attr(
        'role').eq('Manager')
         )
         response_list.extend(scan_response['Items'])

    print( response_list)
```

My loop is running infinitely on the first item only. where is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing the `LastEvaluatedKey` into the `scan()` call, so it is starting the scan over from the beginning each time.

Change it to this:

```
while scan_response.get('LastEvaluatedKey'):
    scan_response = table.scan(
        ExclusiveStartKey=scan_response.get('LastEvaluatedKey'),
        FilterExpression=Attr('id').eq(event['id']) & Attr(
    'name').eq(event['name']) & Attr(
    'role').eq('Manager')
     )
```

Comment: can you answer this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72294085/how-to-delete-multiple-items-from-dynamodb-list-using-python